# What's the point in closing this question?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, close-reasons

I happened to be lucky to answer a highly active question:

[How to increase image size of pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174691/how-to-increase-image-size-of-pandas-dataframe-plot)

Recently after somebody edited the question several times (like removing a "?" from the title), which already runs against Stack Overflow [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

they finally proposed to close the question, originally titled "How to increase image size of pandas.DataFrame.plot in jupyter notebook?" as a duplicate to "How do you change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?" (why not remove the question there as well?).

I'm asking the community if this is an example of fair/ethical behavior and if pandas is a duplicate to matplotlib?

Comment: Apparently, they thought the question was a duplicate. That is a valid reason to close a question as a duplicate. Do you disagree that the question is a duplicate? The solutions look quite similar to me, but I lack the subject-matter expertise to have a real opinion on the matter.

Comment: @CodyGray It's not about a solution. The question was marked as a duplicate, not a solution. As per solution I would dare to say that the referred solution was misplaced and irrelevant to the question asked.

Comment: Note that the proposed duplicate [appears to cover pandas as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770939/5349916), listing all approaches of the pandas-specific question.

Comment: Huh? What does that mean, "the question was marked as a duplicate, not a solution"? When a question is closed as a duplicate, it means that the question already has an answer somewhere else, namely on the linked duplicate.

Comment: @CodyGray Don't you think pandas and matplotlib are different enough?

Comment: In my mind, pandas are the cute furry bear that eats bamboo. I've never seen one try to plot anything. So, I'm not really a good person to judge the technical correctness of this duplicate closure. I'm just trying to nail down what your arguments/objections are, because they seem to be all over the place. It is unclear if you're complaining about inconsistent editing, the fact that this person has the privileges to close a question, the entire notion of duplicate closure, or just whether or not this specific question is a duplicate.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov From your wording, you appear to be asking if one technology is a duplicate to another.  I don't have subject matter expertise, but that's not what the duplicate flag means.  It literally means 'the answer to your question is over here'... which, judging by the answer at the duplicate, it appears to be.  Are you saying that `df.plot(figsize=(3,3));` !== `df['some_column'].plot(figsize=(10, 5))`?  I mean, even the answer referenced in the comment says that that line in question is for pandas.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Daedalus You may query SO database and vote to close half of it. What I'm saying these 2 are completely different questions (by meaning, by wording, by tagging by anything), and finally, if enter a search string into goolge, you'll get the most relevant one, not a simialr answer to a different question.

Comment: *"after somebody edited the question several times"* -  twice, they only edited it twice. And small edits are more of a concern sub 2k where they need reviewed or where they're done in bulk. Those edits are fine.

Comment: A question is suitably closed as a duplicate when the duplicate target contains posts which pretty much answer the problem given. In this case, the solution proposed is to "use the `figsize` parameter". Several answers in the linked question state the same thing (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770939 https://stackoverflow.com/a/66638878 https://stackoverflow.com/a/67180265 etc.). Saying that pandas and matplotlib are different things is a red herring: users of pandas will generally plot data using matplotlib, as was the intent of the asker here.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I didn't use hyperbole in my question, and I'd request that you do the same(eg, telling me to vtc half of all questions isn't needed here).  Apart from the fact that the duplicate answer references a column instead of the entire thing, I don't really see a difference between the two.  I get that the questions are different, but the answer in question, the one referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174691/#comment122447281_51174691), directly references pandas, and the two lines basically match.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator: I disagree, as someone who often searches for answers on SO, having the correct response buried in the middle among 31 answers is not helpful. That's why we moved away from forums. The question should be reopened.

Comment: @user000001 The correct response is not even buried.  [The answer with the highest score](https://stackoverflow.com/a/638443) gives you the `figsize` parameter. No, there is hardly a good reason to reopen this one.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator, ok, but that answer is not using pandas, as this question is asking for. Maybe an answer explaining why using pandas is not recommended should be added to the closed q.

Comment: @user000001 As I already hinted in the previous comment, that is not relevant enough to merit an independent question. Plotting a pandas data frame is still done via matplotlib, and the solution is the same for both.

Comment: “I'm asking the community if this is an example of fair/ethical behavior and if pandas is a duplicate to matplotlib?” - Yes; it’s fair and ethical to close a question that already has an answer as a duplicate

Comment: Sergey is clearly aware that Pandas uses Matplotlib: he added the matplotlib tag to that question.

Comment: @Sergey I guess you need to more clearly explain *why* the general matplotlib dupe target isn't sufficient, and why there needs to be an open question & answer on Pandas-specific issues related to Matplotlib's `figsize` parameter.

Comment: The *"How to ... ?"* form is broken English. They are ***incapable*** of using [the required helper verb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4yWEt0OSpg&t=1m49s). Removing the "?" is one way to turn it into something acceptable for a site for *"[professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)"*. Converting it to [QUASM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kS5NfSzXfrI) is another.

Answer (score 10):

As an alleged subject-matter expert on [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), I feel the question should remain closed.

First let's address the specific question asked:

> I'm asking the community if this is an example of fair/ethical behavior and if pandas is a duplicate to matplotlib?

The `pandas` library has `matplotlib` as a *dependency for visualization* ([Optional Dependencies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html#visualization)) meaning that it is certainly acceptable to close a `pandas` question as a duplicate of `matplotlib` *especially* where plotting is concerned.

But even beyond this, there are lots of problems which have answers that derive from dependencies.

Probably one of the largest examples is [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/15497888) which has 4,164 [linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/588004?lq=1). Many languages have this issue:

1. [PHP - Floating Number Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3726721/15497888)
2. [Is double Multiplication Broken in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1420752/15497888)
3. [Float sum with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12511057/15497888)

These questions can and should be closed as duplicates as the foundational issue is exactly the same, they all rely on the exact same approach for storing numbers causing the exact same behaviour.

Here too there are many modules and libraries that are going to depend on `matplotlib` which means that it is completely reasonable to close them as a duplicate.

---

#### Why do I believe the question should remain closed?

1. There is no meaningful difference between the `figsize` parameter that gets passed to either `pandas.Series.plot` or `pandas.DataFrame.plot` as it will eventually make it to `matplotlib` (assuming the default plotting backend is used as it in this specific question). There is no reason for why there needs to be a separate Q/A just for this one parameter.
2. Even if there was not a `pandas` specific answer already in [How do you change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332289/15497888) I would still support it as a dupe target. Specifically because the second and third answers work without modification. I may need to put a comment that directs to specific answers like:

   - > You should pass `figsize` directly to `plot` -> `df.plot(figsize=(10, 5))`. You could also use `plt.rcParams` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717533/15497888) or create some `subplots` and pass `ax` to `plot` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56941236/15497888)
   - But I do not believe that it is unreasonable to provide some direction when closing as a duplicate. In fact, I believe [Trenton's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174691/how-to-increase-image-size-of-pandas-dataframe-plot?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment122447281_51174691) which links directly to a pandas specific answer in the canonical fulfills this expectation.
3. The closure does not make the question any less relevant. This question exists and is still visible, it is still the first Google result for "how to change figure size pandas". This is unlikely to change. If anything this question is now *more* visible as it is linked to a canonical that has been viewed 4.2 million times. It is currently #3 on the Linked list on the right-hand side of the page. It's now more likely someone looking for a `pandas` specific answer on the canonical is going to see "How to increase image size of pandas.DataFrame.plot" before they see the 6th answer on this thread which is `pandas` specific.

---

#### Can we just make the canonical better instead?

My primary issue with the closure is not whether it is a valid duplicate, because it most certainly is, but rather that, while the canonical has a significant amount of useful information that can be used to answer the question, that information is not as accessible as it could be. [How do you change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332289/15497888) is in a fair bit of disarray, insofar that it is a 12-year-old question with 23 visible answers, several of which are near identical to each other, many of which are now deprecated/no longer working, and many comments which may be better served edited into the answer bodies for visibility.

Personally, I feel that a community effort to clean up the canonical so that all of the wonderful information *already present* can be a better working resource for everyone who needs it.

---

There was also a parenthetical question (which seemed less relevant, so I put it down here):

> originally titled "How to increase image size of pandas.DataFrame.plot in jupyter notebook?" as a duplicate to "How do you change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?" (why not remove the question there as well?).

"How to increase image size of pandas.DataFrame.plot in jupyter notebook?" is not a question as it lacks an auxiliary verb which is why the question mark was removed, while "How do you change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?" has the auxiliary verb **do** which makes it an interrogative in English so the question mark stayed.

Comment: **Can we just make the canonical better instead?** I updated and added clarity to many answers (including [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/334462/7758804) that didn't work), which were rolled back. Subsequent to this post, many answers have been deleted as duplicates, so it's down to 14 visible answers.